# How to debug a power BI connector?

Tags: powerbi, m, powerbi-datasource

I am creating a custom Power BI connector and I have this line of code in my *_PBI.pq

```
headers=[
#"Accept"="application/csv",
#"Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
]

MySec = () => 

let
    m_url="https://myComapny.com/api/",
    m_token="ABCDEFGH",
    myurl=Value.ReplaceType(m_url,Uri.Type),
    mytoken=Value.ReplaceType(m_token,Password.Type),
    My_Dataset=Web.Contents(myurl, [Content = Text.ToBinary("token="&mytoken&"), Headers = headers]),
    Dataset_csv=Csv.Document(My_Dataset)
    Dataset_csv_with_header=Table.PromoteHeaders(Dataset_csv)
   

in
    Dataset_csv_with_header;
```

When I run this connector, it hangs.

I am developing it in VS 2019.

How can I debug it? How can I find which line is the source of the problem?

Is there any way that I can print out (or save it in a file) My_Dataset to check what I am getting from the server to debug the connector?

I am trying to increase the Web.Contents timeout but the following syntax is no correct:

```
My_Dataset=Web.Contents(myurl, [Content = Text.ToBinary("token="&mytoken&"), Headers = headers],Timeout=1000)
```

What is the correct format?

Answer (score 1):

This may have been solved already given the time elapsed since asked - but you're missing a comma between the last two lines of your `let` statement:

```
    Dataset_csv=Csv.Document(My_Dataset) //<------ here
    Dataset_csv_with_header=Table.PromoteHeaders(Dataset_csv)
```